# How to get all paths(vertexes) radiating out of a vertex in Java?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graph-databases, titan

I am using Titan on DynamoDB. i have a directed edge graph with no cycles. Given a vertex, i need all the paths radiating out of that vertex. Path means only list(s) of vertices on each path radiating out of given Vertex.

I just cant understand Gremlin and Groovy, so i hope there exists a solution in Java.

Or is there a Gremlin Query that i can convert to Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dynamodb-titan is based on TinkerPop 3.x and in TinkerPop 3.x Gremlin is not bound to Groovy. Gremlin in Groovy is basically equivalent to Java. You won't get far with Titan (or TinkerPop) if you don't learn Gremlin as it is the only means to query a graph.

Getting a path of a traversal is requires use of the [path()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#path-step) step. To demonstrate I'll use the Gremlin Console, and while it is evaluated with Groovy, I can assure you that you can copy and paste this code to your Java project and it would work equally well there.

First, I create the toy graph that I will demonstrate with:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
```

Next, I write a traversal that finds a single vertex with id of 1 - this will be the vertex that we will use to discover the "radiation path" you are looking for:

```
gremlin> g.V(1)
==>v[1]
```

Then we traverse on out edges to the adjacent vertices from 1:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).out()
==>v[3]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
```

and then we do it again:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).out().out()
==>v[5]
==>v[3]
```

Now, if we want to see the path the traversers took to get there we just do:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).out().out().path()
==>[v[1],v[4],v[5]]
==>[v[1],v[4],v[3]]
```

and there are all the vertices radiating from a single vertex that are a full two steps away from 1.

If you don't know the length of the walk away from the start vertex then you can use [repeat()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#repeat-step):

```
gremlin> g.V(1).repeat(out()).until(outE().count().is(0)).path()
==>[v[1],v[3]]
==>[v[1],v[2]]
==>[v[1],v[4],v[5]]
==>[v[1],v[4],v[3]]
```

Comment: Thanks stephen mallete, this is what i was looking for. How ever, there seems to be a problem. The .out() is to be repeated until it covers all edges that may be connected? how would i know when to stop chaining .out()? I wish i could give you a bounty.

Comment: Updated my answer...again, that should translate directly to java. Note that you will need to [statically import](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#static-imports) the `__` class for that to work there (the console does it for you automatically) which is why my code works without having to do it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks stephen mallette, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: It took a bit of researching but i think the java equivalent after using gremlin-java code is `((GraphTraversal<Object, Vertex>) __.inV()).repeat(__.out()).until(__.outE().count().is(0)).path();`

Comment: The code in my example will work in java. What aspect didn't work in java for you (aside from that cast to `GraphTraversal` with the generics which isn't really related to the query itself)?

Comment: Stephen, many thanks! I just carefully went through the java docs for API and found out what confused me. The Java varargs are not recognized somehow in my IDE. So it started complaining when i did not give values for parameters where it expected. That is how i ended making such a Java Query. Does the use of generic __.out() give the needed information from what we are looking at or unrelated information? Should i instead write g.V(1).out() to get the GraphTraversal interface to execute the out() when i need it? Thanks, now i am looking deeper into how to write code myself. It was confusing.

Comment: Supplying `__out()` to `repeat()` is exactly what you need. `repeat()` and many other steps take an anonymous `Traversal` as an argument and use of `__` is the class that produces that. You don't see the `__` in my code because the groovy console statically imported the class.